# Do dropped items ever expire?

Tags: ingress

When items get dropped and left, do they ever expire or will they be available indefinitely until somebody picks them up?

I believe keys that get dropped by portals when links decay expire in a day or two and vanish. Is there anything like that for manually placed items?

Comment: This question has been answered already:  http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/99995/37963